# How can I find memory leaks in long-running Perl program?

Tags: perl, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

Perl uses reference counting for GC, and it's quite easy to make a circular reference by accident. I see that my program seems to be using more and more memory, and it will probably overflow after a few days.

Is there any way to debug memory leaks in Perl? Attaching to a program and getting numbers of objects of various types would be a good start. If I knew which objects are much more numerous than expected I could check all references to them and hopefully fix the leak.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It may be relevant that Perl *never* gives memory back to the system by itself: It's all up to `malloc()` and all the rules associated with that.

Knowing how `malloc()` allocates memory is important to answering the greater question, and it varies from system to system, but in general most `malloc()` implementations are optimized for programs allocating and deallocating in stack-like orders. Perl uses reference-counting for tracking memory which means that deallocations which means (unlike a GC-based language which uses `malloc()` underneath) it is actually not all that difficult to *tell* where deallocation is going to occur, and in what order.

It may be that you can reorganize your program to take advantage of this fact- by calling `undef($old_object)` explicitly - and in the right order, in a manner similar to the way C-programmers say `free(old_object);`

For long-running programs (days, months, etc), where I have loads of load/copy/dump cycles, I garbage-collect using `exit() and exec()`, and where it's otherwide unfeasible, I simply pack up my data structures (using `Storable`) and file descriptors (using `$^F`) and `exec($0)` - usually with an environment variable set like `$ENV{EXEC_GC_MODE}`, and you may need something similar *even if you don't have any leaks of your own* simply because Perl is leaking small chunks that your system's `malloc()` can't figure out how to give back.

Of course, if you do have leaks in *your* code, then the rest of my advice is somewhat more relevant. It was originally posted [to another question on this subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295385/are-there-any-tools-for-finding-memory-leaks-in-my-perl-program#295461), but it didn't *explicitly* cover long-running programs.

---

All perl program memory leaks will either be an XS holding onto a reference, or a circular data structure. [Devel::Cycle](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Devel-Cycle/) is a great tool for finding circular references, if you know what structures are likely to contain the loops. [Devel::Peek](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Devel-Peek/) can be used to find objects with a higher-than-expected reference count.

If you don't know where else to look, [Devel::LeakTrace::Fast](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Devel-LeakTrace-Fast/) could be a good first place, but you'll need a perl built for debugging.

If you suspect the leak is inside XS-space, it's much harder, and [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) will probably be your best bet. [Test::Valgrind](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Test-Valgrind/) may help you lower the amount of code you need to search, but this won't work on Windows, so you'd have to port (at least the leaky portion) to Linux in order to do this.

Comment: @geocar, this is brilliant!  The only robust method to the inevitable problem of memory leaks in complex perl programs that I know.

Answer (score 5):

[Devel::Gladiator](http://p3rl.org/Devel::Gladiator) is another useful tool in this space.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like the cpan module [Devel::Cycle](http://search.cpan.org/~lds/Devel-Cycle-1.10/lib/Devel/Cycle.pm) is what you are looking for.  It requires making some changes to your code, but it should help you find your references without too many problems.

Answer (score 3):

[valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) is a great linux application, which locates memory leaks in running code. If your Perl code runs on linux, you should check it out.

Comment: I don't think that will work. Perl is an interpreted language. Won't valgrind just point to the memory allocation calls in the Perl interpreter?

Comment: no valgrind can work with Perl, just use the right options. it's documented. it needs to attach itself to the compiled executable not the perl binary.

Comment: valgrind will find memory leaks in XS code, but not in Perl code. Use Devel::Cycle or Devel::Leak for that.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other comments, you may find my [Perl Memory Use talk](http://www.slideshare.net/Tim.Bunce/perl-memory-use-lpw2013) at LPW2013 useful. I'd recommend watching [the screencast](https://archive.org/details/Perl-Memory-Profiling-LPW2013) as it explains the slides and has some cute visuals and some Q&A at the end.

I'd also suggest looking at Paul Evans [Devel::MAT](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::MAT) module which I mention in the talk.