# Memory usage of Perl script

Tags: perl

I have a Perl script, fetch url like `http://1.1.1.1/1.jpg` from MySQL using DBI, and download this jpg file using LWP::Simple. It's a infinite loop.

```
while (1) {
    my $url=&fetch_url_from_mysql;
    if ($url){        
        &download_jpg($url);
    } else {
        sleep 1;
    }
}
```

Plain simple. I suppose the memory usage would be stay in certain amount. But after one month of continuous running of this script. The memory usage is 7.5G!

How can I profile it?

Comment: Is fetch_url_from_mysql opening a new connection every time, and not closing it?

Comment: Yes. I call `DBI::connect` before `while loop`, in `fetch_url_from_mysql` is `prepare,execute,fetch and return $url`

Comment: In washing your code down to a clean example you washed away the parts that actually use memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For profiling, set an explitict exit. Create a counter, and exit from your program if your iteration is equal or bigger than this.

For profiling, use NYTprof:

perl  -d:NYTProf script.pl
nytprofhtml

But you are dealing with a memory leak here.

Read this to find a memory leak: [How can I find memory leaks in long-running Perl program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/429254/how-can-i-find-memory-leaks-in-long-running-perl-program)

Most probably you have a variable that will never be freed. Perl frees memory if a variable goes out of scope, but one of your variables never goes out of scope.

Use $variable=undef to free up the memory.

If you port your whole script maybe we could find a leak in it.

regards,