# Why is %MEM increasing gradually even though I'm using Archive::Tar:Streamed?

Tags: perl, tar

I'm using Archive::Tar::Streamed to archive a 4GB directory containing very small small source code files and some jars. I'm using a system with 4GB RAM and using Archive::Tar::Streamed because I don't want my entire directory to be on the memory as it results in out of memory condition. I reading files one by one from the directory in DFS manner using File::Find and writing it to the tar file using add method in Archive::Tar::Streamed. At any given point of time only one file is residing in the memory, even then %MEM of my perl process is gradually increasing. It got up to 20%. There is no file in my directory that is of 800MB. I have two questions here
1) why is %MEM increasing gradually?
2) Why hast it gone up to 20%. Is it because Archive::Tar is not freeing the memory after it has written the contents to the tar file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not normal for your VSZ memory envelope to grow when you process your data in a stream-oriented manner, and moreso for RES (%MEM) which should normally stabilize in your kind of application.

Therefore I would strongly suspect that cross-references to data are being kept around (e.g. in a hash), or (less likely) that circular-references are generated.

See this post, ["are there any tools for finding memory leaks in my perl program"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295385/are-there-any-tools-for-finding-memory-leaks-in-my-perl-program#295461) for tips on tracing down which variables (be them in your code or in the module you are using) grow the memory envelope or keep cross-references around.